# Appropriate minimum number of observations for VECM?

Tags: references, small-sample, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I have two price series and need to run a Johanssen test for cointegration, followed by a VECM to estimate the cointegrating parameter. My lags tend to be quite short, between 1 and 5 periods.

What is the "appropriate" minimum number of observations: 30? 200? 400? 1000?  (I need to divide the data into sub-periods). 
Is there a paper that estimates VECM on a simulated DGP to determine accuracy vs. observations that verifies this?

Comment: It depends on series, volatility etc... How many observations does it take to estimate $\mu$ where $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu, \sigma^2\right)$? It depends $\sigma^2$ and how precise I need my estimate to be.